How can both WalletConnect and Tron WalletConnect be used together in a single project?
I am making payment gateway system using WalletConnect.
I want to make My app provides Ethereum and Tron with WalletConnectand Tron WalletConnect.
My app functions properly with only WalletConnect, but when I attempt to integrate Tron Wallet Connect, I encounter the following error.
chunk-GGUWXWGC.js?v=479b47fd:1965 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "w3m-button" has already been used with this registry
    at legacyCustomElement (http://localhost:5174/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-GGUWXWGC.js?v=479b47fd:1965:18)
    at http://localhost:5174/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-GGUWXWGC.js?v=479b47fd:1979:99
    at nt (http://localhost:5174/node_modules/.vite/deps/index.es-2YWRQBFO.js?v=479b47fd:93:42)
    at http://localhost:5174/node_modules/.vite/deps/index.es-2YWRQBFO.js?v=479b47fd:106:264

Is there a way to integrate both wallet connect into a single project?
Alternatively, are there any open source dapps that support both chains?
THank you.
Is there a way to integrate both wallet connect into a single project?
Alternatively, are there any open source dapps that support both chains?
